# What is "nervous eczema"?

Tags: stress, nerves, eczema

Is *nervous eczema* a cause from:

- stress? [Bronchial Asthma: A Genetic, Population and Psychiatric Study - Denis Leigh, Edward Marley - Google Books](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=zQzLBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=%22nervous+eczema%22&source=bl&ots=m3Am_HS-rm&sig=rAzJOLzogANaGENrjZF_3Q6bgfc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo8IzUxebYAhWDUZQKHSMhCJIQ6AEINTAF#v=onepage&q=%22nervous%20eczema%22&f=false)
- the nerves? [Nervous Eczema Pictures – 64 Photos & Images / illnessee.com](https://illnessee.com/nervous-eczema-pictures/)

Answer (score -1):

Eczema is caused by nerves that are over sensitive to the surrounding environment or over reactive immune system. 
It is also triggered by stress as the body responds by increasing production of stress hormones like cortisol. Cortisol is a steroid hormone that increases the blood sugar which is essential when facing a fight-or-flight situation. However, it also can hinder the immune system. When this happens, the skin will be more vulnerable to inflammations and wounds as the healing of skin may also get delayed.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].